# Function somehow returning twice from one call

Tags: c, string, gcc

I'm writing a simple program to attempt to implement strtok. Just some practice for myself

I came up with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * stringtok(char * str, char * delim){
    static int last;
    if(str != NULL){ last = 0; }
    char * finder;
    char * result = malloc(100);
    while(delim[0] != '\0'){
        if(finder = strchr(str+last, delim[0])){
            memcpy(result, str + last, finder - str);
            result[finder-str+1] = '\0';
            last = finder - str;
            return result;
        }
        delim++;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(){
    char input[100]="This is my - message - hello can - you hear me?";
    char input2[100] = "-";
    char * pch;




    pch = stringtok(input, input2);
    while(pch != NULL){
        printf("%s\n", pch);
        pch = strtok(NULL, input2);
    }
}
```

When I ./a.out with gcc -ggdb , I get:
"This is my "
Which was strange so I ran it through GDB with breakpoint 22 and I got:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at strtok.c:22
22      int main(){
(gdb) s
23          char input[100]="This is my - message - hello can - you hear me?";
(gdb)
29
(gdb)
stringtok (
    str=0x7fffffffe040 "This is my - message - hello can - you hear me?",
    delim=0x7fffffffdfd0 "-") at strtok.c:7
7           if(str != NULL){ last = 0; }
(gdb)
9           char * result = malloc(100);
(gdb)
10          while(delim[0] != '\0'){
(gdb)
11              if(finder = strchr(str+last, delim[0])){
(gdb)
12                  memcpy(result, str + last, finder - str);
(gdb)
13                  result[finder-str+1] = '\0';
(gdb)
14                  last = finder - str;
(gdb)
15                  return result;
(gdb)
19          return NULL;
(gdb)
main () at strtok.c:30
30          pch = stringtok(input, input2);
(gdb)
31          while(pch != NULL){
(gdb)
This is my
32              printf("%s\n", pch);
(gdb)
30          pch = stringtok(input, input2);
(gdb)
34          }
(gdb)
0x000000363d21ed5d in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb)
Single stepping until exit from function __libc_start_main,
which has no line number information.

Program exited normally.
(gdb)
```

I find it very strange that I have a return result, and then it additionally returns NULL afterward and I'm not really sure why this is happening. Am I just reading the gdb wrong? It looks like it goes from return result to return NULL immediately. Also it looks like my gdb is outputting lines 1 line late, looking at the printf and where the output actually was

Comment: Are you sure gdb is not just jumping to the end of the function? Have you tried printing the actual result? `return` is `return`. It never doesn't "return"

Comment: this is NOT how strtok() works.  strtok changes the original string by replacing (call by call) some found delimiter with '\0'.  if no delimiter is found in the remaining string, return NULL.  It saves a ptr to the next char after the replaced delimiter in static memory.  if the passed in first parameter is NULL, it uses the saved pointer, otherwise it uses the passed in pointer from the first parameter  The posted code adds a requirement that the caller free the returned pointer from the posted code after each call.  This is not what strtok does.

Comment: when 'str' parameter is NULL, this line: ' if(finder = strchr(str+last, delim[0])){' is access memory at some offset from address 0.  That is undefined behaviour and can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: regarding this line: 'char * result = malloc(100);'  1) always check the returned value from malloc (and family) to assure the operation was successful.  2) what if the length of the selected string is greater than 100?

Comment: what if 'delim' has more than one character to check for.   What if 'delim' is NULL rather than a pointer to a string?

Comment: 'last' only contains the last offset into the original string, but the pointer to the original string is not saved.  suggest 'last be a pointer to one past the most recently found delimiter occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Your strtok function doesn't handle `str` being `NULL` properly.  On the first invocation, you need to save the string in addition to the last offset.  Right now, when you call it the second time, you don't have any pointer to the original string anywhere.